# (TextView) setText() method returns blank, not working

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I'm developing `Navigation Drawer` based Android application. `NavMainActivity` handles fragments. `EventFragment`, `HomeFragment`, `ProfileFragment`, etc.

I'm using **Parse SDK** for background jobs. Parse doing its job well.
But in `EventFragment` class, the `TextView`'s `setText()` method does not do anything. I examine this problem and use `Snackbar` and `Toast` to test my background service is working well.

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    /*
    Initiliazing the params and our view.
     */
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    View view;

    boolean isPressed = false;


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public String eventDescription;
    public ParseFile userImage;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    public static EventFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        EventFragment fragment = new EventFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /*
        FloatingAB used for material design guidelines.
        We listen for clicks but in this version user can click many times we need to
        implement opposite button reaction like " Participate " and " Not Participate " state changes.
         */

        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("EventData");
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", "uEglVemWEF");
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (object == null) {
                    Log.d("EventData", "The get the first method request failed!");

                } else {

                    eventDescription = object.getString("eventContext");
                    userImage = object.getParseFile("eventPhoto");

                    Snackbar.make(view, eventDescription, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                }
            }
        });

        TextView z = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.eventDescriptionText);
        z.setText(eventDescription);

        if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getBoolean("eventA")) {
            fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_highlight_remove_24dp);
            isPressed =true;
        }

        return view;

    }
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/HeyVolo.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/darkblue"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/peace"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"

            />



    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:id="@+id/eventDescriptionText"
        android:text="" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_assignment_turned_in_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `eventDescription` is probably null. Try initializing it at the start with some **default value**, you may see that its value is never changed.

Comment: The `getFirstInBackground()` method runs asynchronously, so `eventDescription` won't have been set by the time you call `setText()`. You need to move the `setText()` call to inside of the `done()` method of the `GetCallback` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to fetch eventDescription asynchronously (on a different thread) then using the value in the main thread. It's definitely still null by this time. Try setting the TextView in the `done()` callback in `query.getFirstInBackground`